# Error 500 Server Error if no trailing slash

Tags: url, 2.7.0

New site that we're building in 2.7 is having a weird issue which I don't appear to be able to get any log information about.

we have http://site.com/c/content-url-title-here and if you try accessing this URL we get a 500 Server Error.

However, if we manually add a trailing slash to make the URL http://site.com/c/content-url-title-here/ it loads the page fine.

I can't see anything in the Changelogs that would indicate a specific 2.7 issue around this, has anyone come across this issue?

For Info, this is my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I've never had this issue before and none of my apache logs are giving any errors at all. Anyone able to advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Ignore this question... the issue was somewhere between the keyboard and the chair!

Regards,

Carl

Answer (score 0):

The "content-url-title-here" might be a reserved word. I've had it before with some hosting setups that they have a high-level htaccess file redirecting to a control panel or web service.

Comment: This is on my own server where all other sites are working. Also it's all URL's, not specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issue lately with Option +FollowSymLinks - my htaccess is also a bit different

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^/index.php
RewriteCond $1 !.(css|js|png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: doesn't make any difference...

Comment: could you modify the htaccess to add a trailing slash by default?

Comment: well thats what I thought, but doesn't appear to work either - unless I'm doing it wrong :p

Comment: it's not really a solution though - just treats the symptom